# How to get the text of a combobox in a tablewidget?

Tags: qt

I’m new to Qt, I need help with getting the value of a combobox in a table widget.

I use “setCellWidget” to add a combobox(in my case, its name is “settingA”) to a table widget (the name is “tableWidget_4”):

---

```
QComboBox* settingA = new QComboBox();


settingA->addItem("100");
settingA->addItem("200");

ui->tableWidget_4->setColumnCount(1);
ui->tableWidget_4->setRowCount(3);
ui->tableWidget_4->setCellWidget ( 0, 0, settingA );
```

---

What I want to do here is:
When a button (its name is “ApplyComboButton” in my case) is clicked, I want the value of the combobox(settingA) can be saved into a QStringList(InputComboData) , and this is how I try to do this:

---

```
void MainWindow::on_ApplyComboButton_clicked()
{
 QStringList InputComboData;

 InputComboData << ui->tableWidget_4->item(0,0)->text();

}
```

And it fails.
How can I get the value of my combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [QTableWidget::cellWidget ( int row, int column )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#cellWidget) function to get your QComboBox widget. Use qobject_cast to cast it to QComboBox, and use the [currentText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop) function to get the text.

```
QComboBox *myCB = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ui->tableWidget_4->cellWidget(0,0));
InputComboData << myCB->currentText();
```

Comment: You make this simple to understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use QTableWidget's [cellWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#cellWidget) to get a QWidget* to the widget you set as cellWidget (don't forget to use qobject_cast or dynamic_cast to cast that pointer to a QCombobox*)